# Using find and aspell together

Tags: find, stdin, aspell

I'm trying to spell check all the `*.md` files in my current directory but the following command fails:

```
>> find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.md" | xargs -I {} aspell check {}
xargs: aspell: exited with status 255; aborting
```

I'm assuming this is because `aspell` requires `stdin` to interact with the user and somehow `xargs` doesn't provide it. I found a [hack on Twitter](https://twitter.com/laurencetratt/status/228920802446299136),

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.md" | xargs -n 1 xterm -e aspell check
```

but this opens up a new xterm each time. How can I get my original command to work as if I were to individually run `aspell` on the results of my find command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You don't need `xargs` at all, just use `exec` option:

  ```
  find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.md" -exec aspell check {} \;
  ```
- And just in case you, or any future reader, will really need to use `xargs` - you can do that by spawning new shell and taking standard input from terminal (`/dev/tty`):

  ```
  find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.sh" | xargs -n1 sh -c 'aspell check "$@" < /dev/tty' aspell
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You could always just use a simple loop:

```
for f in *.md; do aspell check "$f"; done
```

Comment: That works, but for pedagogic purposes is it possible to do it with find without spawning a new xterm?

Comment: @Hooked Apparently, yes (see jimmij's answer, which is more extensible if you need more precise criteria for finding the files).

Answer (score 0):

I agree, using `xargs` with `find` is redundant, but if the input comes from something else and you *have* to use `xargs`, just use `-o`:

```
grep -rl 'draft: false' | xargs -o -n1 aspell check --sug-mode=slow
```

`man xargs` has this to say:

> -o      Reopen stdin as /dev/tty in the child process before executing the command.  This is useful if you want xargs to run an interactive
> application.